# Static images not able to redirect

Tags: nginx, ghost-blog

I have an NGINX server which I use to provide reverse proxy services to two Ghost blogging sites. For static content I would like to have it skip over the `node` services and be served directly by NGINX. Should be pretty straight forward but there's a twist.

Here's a config block that sets up the reverse proxy and then provides an exception for static content. This works fine (note: the double bracketed references are replaced with the names of the two different Ghost services I'm using):

```
location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy       true;
    proxy_set_header    Connection          "";
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_cache         ghost_{{slug}}_cache;
    proxy_cache_key     ghost$request_uri$scheme;
    proxy_pass          http://ghost_{{slug}}_upstream;
}

location /assets {
    root                {{assets_root}};    
}
```

So in the case of `/assets` a request like `http://example.com/assets/js/doit.js` and the above configuration would match on `/assets` and then append "assets/js/doit.js" to the root direct defined above. As I said this part WORKS and it works because the location I'm pointing to has the full URL path represented in the file system (e.g., there is a directory `assets/js` with a file `doit.js` in it).

What I'm struggling with -- and I'm very new to NGINX so suspect this is easy -- is the similar situation where you have a configuration block like this:

```
location /content {
    root                {{content_root}};
}
```

This block -- from a configuration and execution standpoint -- is identical to the `assets` block but in this case what I *want* to happen is I want it to pass along only the part of the URL that *follows* **content**. So if the request is `http://example.com/content/images/july/foo.jpg` then what's returns is whatever resides on the filesystem at:

- {{content_root}} + `/images/july/foo.jpg`

instead of what I'm getting right now which is:

- {{content_root}} + **content** + `/images/july/foo.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out an answer to my question ... assuming a URL GET request of `http://example.com/content/js/foobar.js`:

- The original location directive of:

  ```
  location /content {
      root                /var/www/content;
  }
  ```

  Would mistakenly look for the javascript file in the "/var/www/content/**content**" directory
- Instead using the following location directive:

  ```
  location /(content)/ {
      root                /var/www/content;
  }
  ```

  This would correctly look for the file in the "/var/www/content" directory.

Happy days.

Comment: Sadly I'm running into another case of this pattern and my solution doesn't appear to be working in this case :(